# Generate docker-compose.yaml from Helm charts

Tags: kubernetes, docker-compose, kubernetes-helm

I am interested in generating docker-compose.yaml files from Helm charts. Is there a good way or tool to do this?

I realize that this is in the opposite direction from what most people are doing. Why I want to do this:

1. Our production systems run Kubernetes via Helm charts. We've got a full blown k8s and Helm setup already; no need to use a tool like Kompose to get us there. The question is how to convert Helm to docker-compose, not the other way around.
2. We want our Helm charts to be the single authoritative source of container configuration. They are able to describe a superset of what docker-compose can.
3. Running a set of services using Helm on a development machine is more time and resource consuming than running the same set of services via docker-compose. We do not want to slow development down by having engineers run using Helm/k8s.
4. We do not want to maintain two sets of configurations.

Can anybody recommend how to do this, or suggest a different solution to the time/resources issue encountered on development machines?

Comment: I don't think you can easily translate things like multi-container pods, service DNS, or ConfigMaps back to plain-Docker space.  What's the specific resource issue you're encountering?  There are several different local-Kubernetes setups that could work (and don't necessarily involve a dedicated VM).

Comment: The resource issue is the time to iterate. Specifically, if in a suite of services (a, b), I make code changes to b, it takes time n to build and spin up b in docker-compose, whereas it takes time 2*b to build and spin up b using Helm.

Comment: For #3 ("Running a set of services using Helm on a development machine is more time and resource consuming than running the same set of services via docker-compose"), what specifically is the time consuming part? Can't you just "helm install" locally?

Comment: Max, you're correct, it's not necessarily more time consuming.  Underneath the layers and configuration it's all just Docker containers being spun up.  But it is definitely more resource consuming in terms of the number of containers/pods running (to support the features that make up Kubernetes).  Run `kubectl get pods --all-namespaces` to see what I mean.

Comment: Totally agree with your third point, however I think the only way to maintain single application environment both for developers and production is to mimic production locally as close as possible, rather then building workarounds. There are lightweight k8s installations desired to run locally, like [microk8s](https://microk8s.io/) or [k3s](https://k3s.io/, You can either mount local directories inside the pods or use [ksync](https://github.com/ksync/ksync).

Comment: @Mark Which parts of the k8s/helm process do you think takes up the extra time? If you're not using the same container service for image builds there might be an image push? k8s scheduling should only be a few more seconds than compose startup.

Comment: I agree, I also need to convert helm chart to a docker compose. Simply because doing this manually would be too painful. I have generic helm templates and values.yaml file with >1k lines. Stuff can dynamically resolve microservice deps etc. I need to be able to output dry run to a file that could be run on a docker compose. Impossible? I don't think so. Use heuristics. Missing DNS? Drop dns, replace: localhost + internal pod port. Network policy? Drop. Impossible feature? Warn: no support. Even broken output better than nothing - faster to fix few things than write everything from scratch.